# FB Button posting Wrong Title to wall but Linter/debugger correct meta

Tags: post, button, facebook-like, metadata, lint

I have a problem with the facebook like button...

I have a sale running that started today. 
I had a presale page up with like button and message about the sale starting today as the post, this was the same page url as the actual sale page url. (i.e. winter-sale.html used for both pre-sale and sale page).

Now that  he sale is live, I've cleared my own site cache, checked the linter/debugger and the correct meta is coming through, BUT whenever I post through either the same account I "liked" the page when it was a presale (posted sale starts on thursday previously) or through a new account it still displays the post as the pre-sale message (about it starting thursday instead of Sale Starts today).

I even changed the post meta data yesterday and cleared the cache then to try and avoid this happening today, but I still cant get facebook to pickup the new post meta for the button - even with the linter/debugger picking it up correctly.

PLEASE HELP!

Thanks in advance.
M

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will cache the information for a while.  You should try again.  Also try it from a different facebook user account.

Comment: Hi DMCS. As I said above, checked with facebook debugger, cleared site cache and pushed the message for thursday up actually on wednesday to allow for facebook 24hr cache. I also tried from a different account....Still no luck today...